# Trying to send arraylist over socket from Server to Client

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, arraylist

I am trying to send an ArrayList from server to client over socket using ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream but I am getting an error that the object sent is null.
The following should happen (but it doesn't):
1. On the server side the ArrayList is being populated from MySQL database
2.Sent to the client and used to populate jTable.

**Connection file(server side)** I believe that my problem is my void run()...

```
package networkclientserver;  


import java.net.*;  
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;  
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;  
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.Statement;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.logging.Level;  
import java.util.logging.Logger;  


class ConnectionCW implements Runnable   
  {  
    private Socket s;  
    private ObjectOutputStream ooos;  
    private ObjectInputStream oois;  
    ResultSet rs;  


ConnectionCW(Socket s)  
{  
    this.s = s;  
}  


public void run()  
{  
    try  
    {  
        ObjectOutputStream ooos = new ObjectOutputStream(this.s.getOutputStream());  
        ObjectInputStream oois = new ObjectInputStream(this.s.getInputStream());  

        this.getTopology();  
        this.ooos.writeObject(getTopology());  
        this.ooos.flush();  



    } catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionCW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
    }  
}  // end of method run*/  




}  

   public ArrayList<ReadNet> getTopology() throws Exception  
{  
    ArrayList<ReadNet> getTopology2 = new ArrayList<ReadNet>();  

    Connection conn2 = getConnection();  


    String query = "SELECT * FROM  datatopology ";  
    Statement st;  
    st=conn2.createStatement();  
    rs=st.executeQuery(query);  
    ReadNet readNet;  
    while(rs.next())  
    {  
        readNet = new ReadNet(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getInt("numberNodes"),rs.getInt("numberHubs"),rs.getInt("numberSwitches"),rs.getString("topologyStructure"),rs.getString("country"),rs.getString("status"));  
        getTopology2.add(readNet);  
    }  
    return getTopology2;  
}  



public Connection getConnection() throws Exception  
{  
    try  
    {  
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/networkstopology";  
        String username = "user";  
        String password = "pass";  
        Class.forName(driver);  


        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);  
        System.out.println("Connected to MySQL!");  
        return conn;  


    } catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }  
    return null;  
}  
}
```

**Client(run on button press)**

```
private void buttonReadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
{                                               

    try
    {
        ArrayList<ReadNet> setTopology = (ArrayList<ReadNet>) ios.readObject();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) topologyTable1.getModel();
        Object[] row = new Object[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < setTopology.size(); i++)
        {
            row[0] = setTopology.get(i).getId();
            row[1] = setTopology.get(i).getNNodes();
            row[2] = setTopology.get(i).getNHubs();
            row[3] = setTopology.get(i).getNSwitches();
            row[4] = setTopology.get(i).getCountry();
            row[5] = setTopology.get(i).getTopology();
            row[6] = setTopology.get(i).getStatus();
            model.addRow(row);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

**ReadNet class**

```
package networkclientserver;

import java.io.Serializable;

class ReadNet implements Serializable
{
int id;
int nnodes;
int nhubs;
int nswitch;
String topology;
String country;
String status;


ReadNet(int id,int nodes, int hubs, int switches, String countries, String topology, String status)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.nnodes = nodes;
    this.nhubs = hubs;
    this.nswitch = switches;
    this.country = countries;
    this.topology = topology;
    this.status = status;
}

public int getId()
{
return this.id;
}
public int getNNodes()
{
    return this.nnodes;
}

public int getNHubs()
{
    return this.nhubs;
}

public int getNSwitches()
{
    return this.nswitch;
}

String getTopology()
{
    return this.topology;
}

String getCountry()
{
    return this.country;
}

String getStatus()
{
    return this.status;
}
}
```

Comment: 'I am getting an error that the object sent is null.' That can only mean that you sent a null. This equation has nothing do with MySQL, and little or nothing to do with JTable, but it does have to do with [tag:serialization].

Comment: Well I am aware that this is the issue. I do not know how to resolve it that is why I am asking here for advice.

Comment: Err, if you don't want to receive a null, don't send a null? Unclear what kind of advice you're asking for.

Comment: In these lines here it is supposed to send the object which is not null. But for some kind of a reason it doesn't send it. Don't have an idea why is that.

 this.getTopology();  
 this.ooos.writeObject(getTopology());

Comment: Doesn't send anything, or sends null instead of the object? Really this is all most unclear. You haven't posted the actual error message or stack trace or whatever symptom you got. Not answerable in its present form.